# How to make that variable become a value of css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works well.

```
   function changecss() {
     $(".cell").css("background-color", "black");
   }
```

But this code doesn't work

```
   function changecs() {
     $(".cell").css("width", num);
     var num = 33
   }
```

Why the second code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first to declare the variable and assign to it a value. And also the size must have its measurement unit, so append also it (`px` in my case).

```
function changecs() {
     var num = 33;
     $(".cell").css("width", num + 'px'); 
}
```

**Exmple**

```js
const num = 500;
$('#div').css('width', num + 'px');
```

```css
div {
   background-color: red;
   height: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First :**
I see you're creating function `changecss` on the first function and then `changecs` on the second function. If you're using something like `onclick="changecss"` you should rename the second function from `changecs` into `changecss`.

**Second :**
You're creating a variable after call that variable ?
How can javascript got that variable ?

```
function changecs() {
   $(".cell").css("width", num);
   var num = 33
}
```

You're creating variable that sounds like you want to change it easily sometimes you need. Convert the variables into `string`  because the `num` must be string.

It's easy to use rather than typing `+ 'px'` in every `num` you created

```
function changecs() { // or changecss() {
   var width = '33px';
   var height = '33px';
   $(".cell").css('width', width);

   // OR you can use this for more than 1 css
   $(".cell").css({
     'height': height,
     'width': width
   })
}
```

If you want the code run on `somebutton` on click just change your function like this.

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function() {
    var height = '50px';
    var width = '50px';
    $(".cell").css({
        'height': height, 
        'width': width
    })
})
```

Because you're using Jquery for add extra css, so it's better use that jquery function too.

You can check it on the snippet.

```js
$("#buttonid").on("click",function() {
   var height = '100px';
   var width = '100px';
   $(".cell").css({
        'height': height, 
    'width': width
   })
})
```

```css
.cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell">

</div>
<hr>
<button id="buttonid">Click Me to See The Result</button>
```